# Wifi adapters not found in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on HP model 15-db0190nb

Tags: wireless, hp

UPDATE: solved it with [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/) THX for your help <3

I've recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu on my HP (model 15-db0190nb), but can't seem to find out how to get my wifi working.

It has a realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15) and i have a D-Link AC600 MU-MIMomO wifi usb adapter, but none seem to do the trick.

I have been searching on several forums for a solution, but without any real result. Wired connection works fine. I think either my terminal-skills are not that great or I haven't found the right solution yet.

Comment: What does this tell you in terminal `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: SecureBoot enabled

Comment: If so the easiest way is just disabling Secure Boot.

Comment: I've disabled the secure boot, but still can't find the adapters apparently. Noob over here  Thanks for the quick responses, it ensures me that I've made the right decision to get rid of Microsoft!

Comment: Could you write up what you did to fix this as an answer in the answer section to help others? The link might die...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a future reference to the article OP used to solved the problem:

Reboot and go to BIOS to make sure wireless network are enabled. And plug laptop into a wired connection.

Open terminal either via Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut key or by searching for ‘terminal’ from software launcher.

You may first install the building tools first via command:

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git`

Run commands to get newest Realtek wifi drivers:

`git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git`

Install drivers:

`sudo make install`

`cd rtlwifi_new/ && git checkout origin/extended -b extended`

Load drivers with:

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de`

`sudo modprobe rtl8723de`

Note: You may need to research which driver works for your wi-fi device.

You should get wireless signal. If not try these fixes:

If that does not work, you may remove and blacklist the broadcom drivers and restart:

`sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

`sudo sed -i '/blacklist bcma/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

`sudo sed -i '/blacklist brcmsmac/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

In addition, (thanks to jeremy31) if you notice weak signal try command:

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=1`

and see if it is better, if not run:

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2`

(REQUIRED) Or write the rule into configuration. REPLACE X with whatever setting (1, 2, or 3) worked best.

`echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=X" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf`